# fflib-apexmock not getting verified

Tags: apex, unit-test, apexmock, fflib

I am using fflib mocks and [at4dx](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/at4dx/tree/f4348b15b23a31ef327360b6b99c08977402310c)

Trying to test a simple controller method which is calling a selector method.

**Controller Method:**

```
public with sharing class MyController {
   public static String getFieldsByFieldSetName() {
        return JSON.serialize(new MyObjectsSelector().getFieldSets());
    }
}
```

**Selector Class:**

```
public with sharing class MyObjectsSelector extends ApplicationSObjectSelector implements IMyObjectsSelector, IApplicationSObjectSelector {
    public Schema.SObjectType getSObjectType() {
        return MyObject__c.sObjectType;
    }

    public static MyObjectsSelector newInstance(){
        return (IMyObjectsSelector) Application.Selector.newInstance(MyObject__c.SObjectType);
    }

    public override List<Schema.SObjectField> getSObjectFieldList() {
        List<Schema.SObjectField> defaultFields = new List<Schema.SObjectField> {
            MyObject__c.Id
        };

        return defaultFields;
    }

    public override String getOrderBy() {
        return 'Name DESC';
    }

    private List<Schema.SObjectField> getAdditionalSObjectFieldList() {
        return new List<Schema.SObjectField> {};
    }

    public List<FieldSetWrapper> getFieldSets() {
        List<FieldSetWrapper> fieldSetsWrappers = new List<FieldSetWrapper>();
        Map<String, Schema.FieldSet> fieldSetByName = getSobjectType().getDescribe().fieldSets.getMap();

        for (String fieldSetName: fieldSetByName.keySet()) {
            Schema.FieldSet fieldSet = fieldSetByName.get(fieldSetName);
            fieldSetsWrappers.add(new FieldSetWrapper(fieldSet));
        }

        return fieldSetsWrappers;
    }

    public class FieldSetWrapper {
        public FieldSetWrapper(Schema.FieldSet fieldSet) {
            this.fieldSetLabel = fieldSet.getLabel();
            this.fieldSetName = fieldSet.getName();
            this.fields = fieldSet.getFields();
        }

        public string fieldSetLabel;
        public String fieldSetName;
        List<Schema.FieldSetMember> fields;
    }
}
```

**Selector Interface**

```
public interface IMyObjectsSelector extends fflib_ISObjectSelector {
    List<MyObjectsSelector.FieldSetWrapper> getFieldSets();
}
```

**Unit Test Class**

```
@isTest
private class MyControllerClassTest {
    @isTest static void testGetFieldsByFieldSetName() {
        fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();
        //configure mocks
        MyObjectsSelector mockSelector = (MyObjectsSelector) mocks.mock(MyObjectsSelector.class);
        MyObjectsSelector.FieldSetWrapper fieldSetWrapper = 
            new MyObjectsSelector.FieldSetWrapper(
                fflib_ApexMocksUtilsTest.findAnyFieldSet()
            );
        mocks.startStubbing();
        mocks.when(mockSelector.SObjectType()).thenReturn(MyObject__c.SObjectType); // REQUIRED
        mocks.when(mockSelector.getFieldSets()).thenReturn(
            new List<MyObjectsSelector.FieldSetWrapper>{fieldSetWrapper}
        );
        mocks.stopStubbing();

        // Given - Inject mocks
        Application.Selector.setMock(mockSelector);

        // When
        String output = MyController.getFieldsByFieldSetName();

        //Then
        ((MyObjectsSelector) mocks.verify(mockSelector, 1)).getFieldSets();
    }
}
```

I am getting error as:

> fflib_ApexMocks.ApexMocksException: Expected : 1, Actual: 0 -- Wanted
>   but not invoked: MyObjectsSelector__sfdc_ApexStub.getFieldSets().

Can anyone please let me know if I am doing anything wrong here?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller is instantiating the selector directly instead of using the static newInstance method. With out this, your setting of the mock selector in the Application factory class is useless. Change the reference in the controller to use the Application factory